# Logical error in React useEffect and conditional statement

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, use-state

I have recently asked a question about infinite loop caused by useState in React, and I got help. But now I have another bug with same code;

```
const [scoutMode, setScoutMode] = useState("");
const [bottomLinks, setBottomLinks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

setScoutMode("weeklyProgramme");

if (scoutMode == "weeklyProgramme") {
  setBottomLinks(["x", "y"])
  console.log("weeklyprogramme");

} 
else if (scoutMode == "camp") {
  setBottomLinks(["a", "b"])
  console.log("camp");

} 

else {
  setBottomLinks(["c", "d"]);
  console.log("None")
}
console.log(bottomLinks);
}, [scoutMode])
```

I expected that it writes ["x", "y"] and "weeklyprogramme" in console because obviously the first condition is true, but instead the output is like this:
[picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGSF9.png)

It looks like it runs partly the first condition's statements and also the else statement. Could somebody explain? Does React or hook work unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0):

`setBottomLinks()` is the asynchronous method so you can't get the updated value of `bottomLinks`  immediately after `setBottomLinks()`.

```
    setBottomLinks(...)
    console.log(bottomLinks) // This will console old value of bottomLinks
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding a `bottomLinks` dependency to check the updated state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(bottomLinks) 
}, [bottomLinks]);
```